# Lazy loading for child routes is not redirecting to child

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi for me parent routing is working fine, but for chid routes it is not redirecting and not getting errors also

in app.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'card',
    loadChildren: './cards/cards.module#CardsModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'card/:id',
    loadChildren: './cards/cards.module#CardsModule',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }]
```

in card-routing:

```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Cardscomponent } from './cards.component';
import { AuthGuard } from '../_services/auth.guard';
import { CardDetailsComponent } from './card-details/card-details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: Cardscomponent,
    children :[
      { path: ':id', component: CardDetailsComponent}
    ]
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class CardsRoutingModule { }
```

**localhost:4200/card** is working
but **localhost:4200/card/1234**  is not working and not getting any error also, any help...

Comment: not getting any error , not going to details page

Comment: You dont have to handle child's routes in parent.  Try removing 'card/:id' from parent router

Comment: Removed card:id from parent router, url is forming  as localhost:4200/card/1234 but not going to detailscomponent

Comment: `path: 'id'` shoiud be `path: ':id'`

Comment: @Kenny changed but same result, is my both files correct

Comment: Is your CardRoutingModule correctly imported into your CardsModule? Have you imported and exported RouterModule in CardsRoutingModule? Have you called RouterModule.forChild(routes) on the import?

Comment: @WillAlexander updated my question with full cardsRouting module

Comment: @WillAlexander any help

Comment: @kenny any help

Comment: @Ms.Tamil any help

Comment: Remove the second route in AppRoutingModule

Comment: Removed card:id from parent router, url is forming as localhost:4200/card/1234 but not going to detailscomponent -- Do you have a router-outlet in child component. Usually missing router outlet cause this kind of issue[URL changing but component not rendered]

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have `router-outlet` in child component.

When the url updated but view not rendered, it usually comes down to missing router-outlet. 
Learned that from developing a entire project with angular elements.

If you **enable tracing**, you can see all the router events are triggered successfully.

Comment: is my both router files are correct, can you give any example how to work with  child routes